# Build Only the Core Files of spark

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

So I am working on Apache Spark, since I want to use Spark 2.1.0 with Scala 2.10.6 I am using the following command to build spark found [Here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html)

```
./build/mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dscala-2.10 -DskipTests clean package
```

I am working on making some changes for my project to the spark core files (SparkContext.scala mainly). Every time I make some changes I have to rebuild spark using the command given above, which takes considerable amount of time. Even adding a simple print I have to build it all over again. Though doing so seems to work as my changes are visible when I run my spark application using the command

```
spark-submit --master local[*] --driver-memory 256g --class main.scala.TestMain target/scala-2.10/spark_proj-assembly-1.0.jar
```

Now the link says spark lets you build modules, And I found online the following command to build the spark core only,

```
/build/mvn -pl core clean  package -DskipTests -Dscala-2.1
```

And it seems to work as spark compiles the core and shows me errors if I have any, but when I run my application, I do not see the changes at runtime, any prints I have dont show or any operations I apply are not there either. Its like my program is still using the version of spark before I build the core files only.  Though building the entire spark seems to work.

Can some one help me here, as in whats wrong, why only building the core does not work properly, or am I using the wrong command, if so can some one tell me how exactly to build only the core files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `./build/mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dscala-2.10 -DskipTests clean package`
>
> Every time I make some changes I have to rebuild spark using the 
>   command given above, which takes considerable amount of time

If you're only making incremental changes, omit the "clean" phase after the first build. Including it causes Maven to rebuild the entire codebase, whereas if you don't

```
./build/mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dscala-2.10 -DskipTests package
```

then Maven will only recompile and re-package your updated files.